# How to are long process-names stored in _EPROCESS

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel, windbg

The windows _EPROCESS (http://terminus.rewolf.pl/terminus/structures/ntdll/_EPROCESS_x64.html) structure has a field `ImageFileName` that is declared like this:

Using WinDbg:

```
ImageFileName    : [15] UChar
```

So there is space for 15 characters.

How are process-names with more than 15 characters stored?

Comment: short answer - they are cut of. The ImageFileName in the kernel _EPROCESS structure is not the one that is used by task manager and the like mind you. I would assume they get there information through the PEB.

Comment: There's a `SectionObject` at offset 0x1F0.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - task manager use `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemExtendedProcessInformation`. this internal call `SeLocateProcessImageName` for get process name.

Comment: @RbMm - good to know but I'm not sure if that OP wants to know *where* to get the information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

look for exported but undocumented api :

```
NTSTATUS
SeLocateProcessImageName(
    __in PEPROCESS Process,
    __deref_out PUNICODE_STRING *pImageFileName
    )

/*++

Routine Description

    This routine returns the ImageFileName information from the process, if available.  This is a "lazy evaluation" wrapper 
    around SeInitializeProcessAuditName.  If the image file name information has already been computed, then this call simply
    allocates and returns a UNICODE_STRING with this information.  Otherwise, the function determines the name, stores the name in the 
    EPROCESS structure, and then allocates and returns a UNICODE_STRING.  Caller must free the memory returned in pImageFileName.

Arguments

    Process - process for which to acquire the name

    pImageFileName - output parameter to return name to caller

Return Value

    NTSTATUS. 

--*/
```

in `EPROCESS` structure exist member `SE_AUDIT_PROCESS_CREATION_INFO SeAuditProcessCreationInfo;` (of course this structure not public and very volatile - different in any os version)

```
struct SE_AUDIT_PROCESS_CREATION_INFO {
    OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION * ImageFileName;
};
```

the [`OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-obquerynamestring) is declared in *wdm.h*. but of course we can not direct access  `SeAuditProcessCreationInfo` because layout of `EPROCESS` is unknown. you can call `SeLocateProcessImageName` or [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280(v=vs.85).aspx)